# How to avoid ansible git module storing credentials?

Tags: git, ansible

I have noticed that the ansible git module is storing credentials (username/password) while the using the following module
How to fix this? Please advice.

```
- name: pull v016 repo from git
    git: repo=https://{{ githubuser }}:{{ githubpassword|urlencode }}@git.abc.com/abc/abc.git
         dest=/tmp/test/abc
         accept_hostkey=yes
         update=yes
         clone=no
         force=yes
         remote=origin
         version=20190524v016
```

I have tried to use the git-credential-cache to avoid storing passwords in plain text, but it is not working as expected.

As a stop gap solution i'm using git set-url command to avoid others facing issues while running playbook.

Comment: Why not use an SSH keypair and SSH URL?

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, from what i gather reading documents, to use ssh keypair and URL, there are prerequisites like, ssh agent forwarding to be enabled on the remote systems , which may not be easy to check and configure





Please correct me if i'm wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a SSH keypair which would be a better solution, you could use prompts and reference the username / password instead.

Taken from the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html):

> When running a playbook, you may wish to prompt the user for certain
>   input, and can do so with the ‘vars_prompt’ section.
>
> A common use for this might be for asking for sensitive data that you
>   do not want to record.

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:

    - name: username
      prompt: "What is your username?"
      private: no

    - name: password
      prompt: "What is your password?"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: 'Logging in as {{ username }}'
```

It's also worth noting that user input is hidden by default, also suggested by the docs.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i have in the playbook at the moment..

vars_prompt:
    - name: "githubuser"
      prompt: "Enter your github username"
      private: no
    - name: "githubpassword"
      prompt: "Enter your github password"
      private: yes

But it still the credentials gets cached and when another user is trying to run the playbook it gives an error like below

Authentication failed for 'https://mohan..........'